# Spark inner join produces invalid result when number of executors is greater than 1

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark job running with a small dataset representing Marvel characters and movies. Everything works fine when `spark.executor.instances=1` but anything greater than one executor produces invalid results in a `join` operation.

Snippets of both:

DF1:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Donald J. Blake |
| 1 | William Blinn |
| 2 | Chad |
| .... | ... |
| 21 | Tony Stark |
| 119 | List |
| 121 | Bruce Banner |
| 434 | Gao |
| 528 | Maria Collins Carbonell Stark |

DF2:

| name | out |
| --- | --- |
| Tony Stark | Iron Man |
| List | Captain America: The Winter Soldier |
| Bruce Banner | The Incredible Hulk |

The indices of DF1 were generated via `zipWithIndex()`. When I `collect()` and `println` these `Dataset`s, everything looks great. The next step in our data transformation is this line:

```
DF2.join(DF1, DF2("name").equalTo(DF1("name")))
```

When I do a `show()`, I see incorrect `ids` like the following:

| name | out | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tony Stark | Iron Man | 434 | Tony Stark |
| List | Captain America: The Winter Soldier | 528 | List |
| Bruce Banner | The Incredible Hulk | 530 | Bruce Banner |

Again, when there is only *one* executor, this works as expected. I've tried broadcasting DF1 but that didn't change anything and seems unnecessary as these are both very small Dataframes. I feel like there is something very basic I'm not understanding about how Spark would distribute these Dataframes across multiple executors. I'm running this on a 3 node K3s cluster and can see the executors spin up as expected but the results seem to be incorrect that are produced.

Comment: It's (extremely) strange that the number of executors affects Spark output. Can you provide a standalone code that reproduces the issue?